# Unable to pull any image from Docker public repository

Tags: docker, ubuntu, wsl-2, windows-11, docker-engine

I am unable to pull any image from the Docker public repository.
Until yesterday, everything was OK.

Nothing had changed in my network configuration.
No VPN, no proxy, working at home - connection at 540 Mbps according to fast.com.

I am using docker engine on Ubuntu 22.04 running inside WSL

Host Operating System:
Windows 11 Professionnal - Version 22H2 - Build 22621.819

```
$ docker -v

Docker version 20.10.19, build d85ef84
```

I have tried:

- changed the default DNS to dns_google (8.8.8.8)
- restarted the docker demon
- restarted WSL
- restarted the computer
- connected to the internet on another network (4G)
- flushed the DNS info locally (ipconfig /flushdns on Windows CMD)
- searched for any reports of unavailability, change of rules on docker official site.

I was expecting the image to be downloaded to my local computer to be used by docker,
but I got this:

`$ docker pull hello-world`

Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon:

```
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on <my_ip>:53: read udp <my_ip>:42896-><my_ip>:53: read: connection refused
```

Comment: You have a problem with your dns server (local or forwarder). This is off-topic on SO, try https://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator. In fact, it was a network issue - not only DNS, but also related to other settings. Solved by resetting the windows network like this: ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int ip reset c:\tcp.txt
netsh winsock reset

Comment: Please make the final comment into an answer and accept it.